# Six coins and a die

Tags: probability

I have a die and six coins on a board such that every second shows head and every second shows tail in the beginning. Every turn I throw a die to get some number $n\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and turn the coin number $n$. How can I compute the expected number of throws that coins are all either head or all are tail?

I tried to model it as first we have three heads and then with probability $1/2$ we have four and with probability $1/2$ two heads. But after that we might return to original state of get a new state. So how can I compute the expected value correctly?

Comment: Sounds like your currecnt subject is Markov processes?

Comment: Side note: "dice" is plural. The singular is "die".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are the following states possible: $3:3$, $4:2$, $5:1$, and $6:0$ (because we may identify $x:y$ with $y:x$ as both $6 heads as well as 6 tails are a "win").

Let $f(n)$ denote the expected number of rolls when starting in $(6-n):n$.
Clearly, $$f(0)=0.$$ From $(6-n):n$, we have a chance of $\frac n6$ of going to $(7-n):(n-1)$; otherwise we go to $(5-n):n+1$.
Therefore, 
$$ f(1)=1+\frac16f(0)+\frac 56 f(2),$$
$$ f(2)=1+\frac26f(1)+\frac 46 f(3),$$
and finally
$$ f(3)=1+f(2).$$
You can solve these linear equations for the desired $f(3)$.

Comment: So I got $f(3)=37$.